# Android Navigation Drawer displaying empty google map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, navigation-drawer

I'm currently working on an Android app which shows different things on maps. I have a Navigation Drawer which works perfectly and some Google Maps Activities which return nearby places like restaurants and places to eat. The problem is that when I click on the navigation drawer item meant to open the Map Activity, it loads the basic map and nothing else. I would like to add that the Map Activity works perfectly in a separate project. Below you can find my code.
   The code for NavigationActivity :

```
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
  import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
  import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  import com.example.gabrielab.proiectdefinitiv.MainActivity;
  import com.example.gabrielab.proiectdefinitiv.Maps.EatAndDrinkActivity;
  import com.example.gabrielab.proiectdefinitiv.Maps.MuseumActivity;


  import org.json.JSONObject;

public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

JSONObject response, profile_pic_data, profile_pic_url;
TextView user_name, user_email;
ImageView user_picture;
NavigationView navigation_view;
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
NavigationView navigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String jsondata = intent.getStringExtra("jsondata");

    setNavigationHeader();    // call setNavigationHeader Method.
    setUserProfile(jsondata);  // call setUserProfile Method.


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

/*
    Set Navigation header by using Layout Inflater.
 */

public void setNavigationHeader(){

    navigation_view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

    View header = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.nav_header_navigation, null);
    navigation_view.addHeaderView(header);

    user_name = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.username);
    user_picture = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
    user_email = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.email);
}

public  void  setUserProfile(String jsondata){

    try {
        response = new JSONObject(jsondata);
        user_email.setText(response.get("email").toString());
        user_name.setText(response.get("name").toString());
        profile_pic_data = new JSONObject(response.get("picture").toString());
        profile_pic_url = new JSONObject(profile_pic_data.getString("data"));

        Picasso.with(this).load(profile_pic_url.getString("url"))
                .into(user_picture);

    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_logout){

        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
        Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }  else if (id == R.id.nav_culture) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this, MuseumActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_eat) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this, EatAndDrinkActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_coffee) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_parks) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_shopping) {

    }else if(id==R.id.nav_hospitals){

    }else if(id==R.id.nav_transportation){

    }else if(id==R.id.nav_search){

    }else if(id==R.id.nav_tripplanner){

        Intent intent = new Intent(NavigationActivity.this, RoutingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

And the code for the Map Activity

```
 import android.Manifest;
 import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.gabrielab.proiectdefinitiv.R;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsEatAndDrink extends AppCompatActivity implements
       GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener,
    OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LatLng latLng;
double mLatitude = 0;
double mLongitude = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_museum);

    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
}




@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        return;
    }
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    buildGoogleApiClient();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder(sbMethod());
    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();
    placesTask.execute(sbValue.toString());
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    //Unregister for location callbacks:
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
    {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
{
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) throws SecurityException
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    // Get the name of the best provider
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    // Get Current Location
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    // Get latitude of the current location
    double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
    // Get longitude of the current location
    double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
    // Create a LatLng object for the current location
    latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    //mGoogleMap.clear();
    //latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
    Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    m.showInfoWindow();
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
    Toast.makeText(this,"Touch the Pink Markers to view the details of that Hospital",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this,"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

public StringBuilder sbMethod() throws SecurityException
{
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    mLatitude=myLocation.getLatitude();
    mLongitude=myLocation.getLongitude();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
    sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
    sb.append("&radius=40000");
    sb.append("&types=" + "restaurant|meal_delivery|fast_food|bakery|bar|liquor_store|meal_takeaway|");
    sb.append("&sensor=true");

    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyCxSpR3eT4wPPNn-TulLh9Lqk47NBrlOz0");

    Log.d("Map", "url: " + sb.toString());

    return sb;
}

private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{

    String data = null;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParserTask
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException
{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();

        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}

private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

    JSONObject jObject;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
        Place_JSON placeJson = new Place_JSON();

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            places = placeJson.parse(jObject);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return places;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

        Log.d("Map", "list size: " + list.size());
        // Clears all the existing markers;
        //mGoogleMap.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

            // Creating a marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Getting a place from the places list
            HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);


            // Getting latitude of the place
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

            // Getting longitude of the place
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

            // Getting name
            String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

            Log.d("Map", "place: " + name);

            // Getting vicinity
            String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

            latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

            // Setting the position for the marker
            markerOptions.position(latLng);

            markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));

            // Placing a marker on the touched position
            Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    }
}
public class Place_JSON {

    /**
     * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
     */
    public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

        JSONArray jPlaces = null;
        try {
            /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
            jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
         * where each json object represent a place
         */
        return getPlaces(jPlaces);
    }

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces) {
        int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
        List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> place = null;

        /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
        for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
            try {
                /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
                place = getPlace((JSONObject) jPlaces.get(i));
                placesList.add(place);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return placesList;
    }

    /**
     * Parsing the Place JSON object
     */
    private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace)
    {

        HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String placeName = "-NA-";
        String vicinity = "-NA-";
        String latitude = "";
        String longitude = "";
        String reference = "";

        try {
            // Extracting Place name, if available
            if (!jPlace.isNull("name")) {
                placeName = jPlace.getString("name");
            }

            // Extracting Place Vicinity, if available
            if (!jPlace.isNull("vicinity")) {
                vicinity = jPlace.getString("vicinity");
            }

            latitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
            longitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
            reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

            place.put("place_name", placeName);
            place.put("vicinity", vicinity);
            place.put("lat", latitude);
            place.put("lng", longitude);
            place.put("reference", reference);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return place;
    }
}
```

}

I know that the navigation drawer works better with fragments but I couldn't figure it out a proper way to turn my Map Activity into a fragment without losing any functionality. Any advice is helpful. Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days you absolutely need to use Fragments with a NavigationDrawer.

As for converting your Map Activity to a Fragment, it's not so hard.

I just did a quick conversion for you, note that it now extends SupportMapFragment instead of AppCompatActivity.
Also note that it doesn't need to inflate any layout xml, it doesn't even need an `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()` override.
Just call `getMapAsync()` from the `onResume()` override.
Also, wherever you use `this` for a Context, just replace it with `getActivity()`.

Here's the modified class code:

```
public class MapsEatAndDrink extends SupportMapFragment implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        OnMapReadyCallback {
    //.......

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

       mGoogleMap = googleMap;
       if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           // TODO: Consider calling
           //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
           // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
           //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
           //                                          int[] grantResults)
           // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
           // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
           return;
       }
       mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
       buildGoogleApiClient();
       mGoogleApiClient.connect();
       StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder(sbMethod());
       PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();
       placesTask.execute(sbValue.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
       super.onPause();
       //Unregister for location callbacks:
       if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
       {
           LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
       }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
       mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
               .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
               .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
               .addApi(LocationServices.API)
               .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) throws SecurityException
    {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
       LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
       Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
       // Get the name of the best provider
       String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
       // Get Current Location
       Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
       // Get latitude of the current location
       double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
       // Get longitude of the current location
       double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
       // Create a LatLng object for the current location
       latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

       //mGoogleMap.clear();
       //latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
       MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
       markerOptions.position(latLng);
       markerOptions.title("Current Position");
       markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
       Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
       m.showInfoWindow();
       mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
       mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));
       Toast.makeText(this,"Touch the Pink Markers to view the details of that Hospital",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnectionSuspended",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
       Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"onConnectionFailed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    public StringBuilder sbMethod() throws SecurityException
    {
       LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
       String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
       Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
       mLatitude=myLocation.getLatitude();
       mLongitude=myLocation.getLongitude();

       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
       sb.append("location=" + mLatitude + "," + mLongitude);
       sb.append("&radius=40000");
       sb.append("&types=" + "restaurant|meal_delivery|fast_food|bakery|bar|liquor_store|meal_takeaway|");
       sb.append("&sensor=true");

       sb.append("&key=AIzaSyCxSpR3eT4wPPNn-TulLh9Lqk47NBrlOz0");

       Log.d("Map", "url: " + sb.toString());

       return sb;
    }

    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {

       String data = null;

       // Invoked by execute() method of this object
       @Override
       protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
           try {
               data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
           }
           return data;
       }

       // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

           // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
           // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParserTask
           parserTask.execute(result);
       }
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException
    {
       String data = "";
       InputStream iStream = null;
       HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
       try {
           URL url = new URL(strUrl);

           // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
           urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

           // Connecting to url
           urlConnection.connect();

           // Reading data from url
           iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

           StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

           String line = "";
           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               sb.append(line);
           }

           data = sb.toString();

           br.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
       } finally {
           iStream.close();
           urlConnection.disconnect();
       }
       return data;
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

       JSONObject jObject;

       // Invoked by execute() method of this object
       @Override
       protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

           List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;
           Place_JSON placeJson = new Place_JSON();

           try {
               jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

               places = placeJson.parse(jObject);

           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
           }
           return places;
       }

       // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> list) {

           Log.d("Map", "list size: " + list.size());
           // Clears all the existing markers;
           //mGoogleMap.clear();

           for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {

               // Creating a marker
               MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

               // Getting a place from the places list
               HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);


               // Getting latitude of the place
               double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));

               // Getting longitude of the place
               double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

               // Getting name
               String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

               Log.d("Map", "place: " + name);

               // Getting vicinity
               String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

               latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

               // Setting the position for the marker
               markerOptions.position(latLng);

               markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);

               markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));

               // Placing a marker on the touched position
               Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
           }
       }
    }
    public class Place_JSON {

       /**
        * Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
        */
       public List<HashMap<String, String>> parse(JSONObject jObject) {

           JSONArray jPlaces = null;
           try {
               /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
               jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
            * where each json object represent a place
            */
           return getPlaces(jPlaces);
       }

       private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces) {
           int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
           List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
           HashMap<String, String> place = null;

           /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
           for (int i = 0; i < placesCount; i++) {
               try {
                   /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
                   place = getPlace((JSONObject) jPlaces.get(i));
                   placesList.add(place);
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
           return placesList;
       }

       /**
        * Parsing the Place JSON object
        */
       private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace)
       {

           HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
           String placeName = "-NA-";
           String vicinity = "-NA-";
           String latitude = "";
           String longitude = "";
           String reference = "";

           try {
               // Extracting Place name, if available
               if (!jPlace.isNull("name")) {
                   placeName = jPlace.getString("name");
               }

               // Extracting Place Vicinity, if available
               if (!jPlace.isNull("vicinity")) {
                   vicinity = jPlace.getString("vicinity");
               }

               latitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
               longitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
               reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

               place.put("place_name", placeName);
               place.put("vicinity", vicinity);
               place.put("lat", latitude);
               place.put("lng", longitude);
               place.put("reference", reference);

           } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return place;
       }
    }
}
```